# customizing output from database and formatting it

Tags: sql, text, format

Say you have an average looking database. And you want to generate a variety of text files (each with their own specific formatting - so the files may have rudimentary tables and spacing). So you'd be taking the data from the Database, transforming it in a specified format (while doing some basic logic) and saving it as a text file (you can store it in XML as an intermediary step).

So if you had to create 10 of these unique files what would be the ideal approach to creating these files? I suppose you can create classes for each type of transformation but then you'd need to create quite a few classes, and what if you needed to create another 10 more of these files (a year down the road)?

What do you think is a good approach to this problem? being able to maintain the customizability of the output file, yet not creating a mess of a code and maintenance effort?

Comment: It seems you are looking for [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) help, but you should do specific questions ( programing language, database brand, ... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would do if I were to come up with a general approach to this vague question. I would write three pieces of code, independent of each other:

a) A query processor which can run a query on a given database and output results in a well-known xml format.

b) An XSL stylesheet which can interpret the well-known xml format in (a) and transform it to the desired format.

c) An XML-to-Text transformer which can read the files in (a) and (b) and put out the result.

Comment: So if you needed 20 different transformations you would create 20 stylesheets? What about the approach where you create 20 classes, and query the database directly is that much worse?

Comment: @regular: by definition, if you indeed have 20 different transformations, then you need 20 different 'things' to express that difference. And for your 2nd question, remember the DRY principle.

Comment: I know this is a pretty generic so far, but is it reasonable to develop a framework, so that a non-programmer can use a gui to create these transformations with ease?